# How to build an extension in Python debugging environment?

Tags: python-extensions

I'm trying to debug a Python extension that I wrote. In order to enable some memory debugging features I downloaded and built a Python version, which worked just fine. Now I'm trying to build my own package using that environment, but it fails due to the linker not finding the libpython.x.x.a static library.

```
building 'clusterline.cwsf.parser' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -Og -Wall -DPy_DEBUG -fPIC -I/usr/local/src/python/Python-3.6.8/Include -I/usr/local/src/python/Python-3.6.8 -c clusterline/cwsf/parser.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6-pydebug/clusterline/cwsf/parser.o
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6-pydebug/clusterline/cwsf/parser.o -L. -lpython3.6d -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6-pydebug/clusterline/cwsf/parser.cpython-36d-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.6d
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Note that the library is present. What's missing is a "-L/usr/local/src/python/Python-3.6.8" linker flag. Why isn't it there, and how to get it there?

```
$ ls /usr/local/src/python/Python-3.6.8/*.a
```

Maybe I'm just spoilt by Python -- normally everything falls into place when calling /path/to/venv/bin/python, why doesn't that work in this case? I must be missing something essential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thou shalt not use ./configure --enable-shared and --with-pydebug at the same time.